# Crear Ruta Relativa en Java

Tags: java

Tengo una base de datos local  y quiero que se acceda a ella por una ruta relativa porque no todo el mundo tiene la misma ruta que la mia.
Ejemplo:
home/montenegro/NetBeansProjects/SistemaCRUD/db -> esta es mi ruta absoluta y quiero aceder a ella por una ruta relativa. Espero me ayuden.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Te recomiendo usar [JNDI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=jndi) :)